# Solucionar error en Jasper Report: Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Tags: java, jasper-reports

He creado un scriptlets en java, al momento de ejecutar la vista previa del reporte e invocar a la función del scriptlets me marca el siguiente error:

> Error filling print... java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: numeroletras/NumeroletrasScriptlet : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 null
>   java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: numeroletras/NumeroletrasScriptlet : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

La versión que utilizo de Jasper Report es la 4.6 y la versión de java instalada es la 1.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error que tienes no es asociado a Jasper, sino a la versión de Java que utilizas. Al parecer el jar (sea de Jasper o de otra librería o quizás de tu propio código) fue compilado utilizando Java 7 y el código lo estás ejecutando desde una JVM 6 o inferior. Te recomiendo revisar la siguiente tabla de versiones:

```
Java SE 9 = 53,
Java SE 8 = 52,
Java SE 7 = 51,
Java SE 6.0 = 50,
Java SE 5.0 = 49,
JDK 1.4 = 48,
JDK 1.3 = 47,
JDK 1.2 = 46,
JDK 1.1 = 45
```

(Fuente: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file).

Puedes identificar al archivo (o archivos) culpable(s) al abrir el compilado, el .class, y ver en el hexadecimal al comienzo del archivo lo siguiente:

```
CA FE BA BE 51
```

Solución: utiliza una JVM 7 o superior para ejecutar tu proyecto. Para asegurarte que realmente utilizas Java 7 al ejecutar tu proyecto, abre una línea de comandos (cmd, shell, etc) y ejecuta lo siguiente

```
java -version
```

Debería aparecer que utilizas la versión 7. De lo contrario, quizás no utilizas Java 7 en tu proyecto.

Comment: Efectivamente el problema era la versión que utilice para compilar la clase en java. En Jaspert Report tenia la misma versión que la que ocupe para compilar en este caso 1.7. Aun así me mostraba el erro ya mencionado. La solución a mi problema fue cambiar al versión de compilación tanto del  Jaspert Report como de Java a la 1.6 y volver a generar el .jar desde java. Gracias @Luiggi